# Redirect all https non www traffic to www on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Having trouble getting our **non www** https traffic to redirect to https://www

Currently our domain registrar has web forwarding setup for the http traffic so its working for that but waiting to see if they'll support https as well. We have the following in our `.htaccess` to direct all traffic to https:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/status\.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/_hostmanager/
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

I know Elastic Beanstalk handles https requests a little differently hence the `HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto`. We've tried all the answers on here and nothing has worked so far.

Should we turn off web forwarding with our domain registrar and have the `.htaccess` handle non www redirects for both http and https requests? If so how do we set that up in the `.htaccess` along with  redirecting all traffic to https?

Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what you tried and what didn't work?  Does your EB environment have a load balancer, and are you using the load balancer to terminate HTTPS?

Comment: *"Currently our domain registrar has web forwarding setup for the http traffic so its working for that but waiting to see if they'll support https as well.*" That's extremely, extremely unlikely.  Intuitively, that's a question not even worth asking. They would need a copy of your SSL certificate and would need to be set up for something like this... They can't redirect what they can't accept, and without your SSL cert, they can't accept those https requests on your behalf.

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys, @Michael-sqlbot that makes sense but they seem to think they can do it, they say they've enabled it but its still not working at this end.

Comment: @James yes the EB environment has a load balancer, I'm just using the default settings so not sure if it is terminating HTTPS, the https://www routes work though. Sorry it's hard to say what I have tried as I pretty much went through every response on here to similar questions. The last one was this: `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ https%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>`